# Implementing Y86 Fetch Instruction in C

Tags: c, cpu, y86

Sorry for the long question, but I'm really lost on this assignment. I'm essentially asked to implement the fetchInstruction. The other two are helper functions I'm supposed to use, I guess. I attached the fetchInstruction.c code and instruction.h code below. I'm not expecting straight up answers and completed code, but could someone point me into the right direction on how to start this? In case for those wondering, programMap refers to the memory itself and location is the location of the instruction.

```
/* Reads one byte from memory, at the specified address. Stores the
     read value into *value. Returns 1 in case of success, or 0 in case
     of failure (e.g., if the address is beyond the limit of the memory
     size). */
int memReadByte(machine_state_t *state, uint64_t address, uint8_t *value)
{
    if (address > machine_state->programSize)
       return 0;
    *value = machine_state->programMap[address];
    return 1;
}

/* Reads one quad-word (64-bit number) from memory in little-endian
     format, at the specified starting address. Stores the read value
     into *value. Returns 1 in case of success, or 0 in case of failure
     (e.g., if the address is beyond the limit of the memory size). */
int memReadQuadLE(machine_state_t *state, uint64_t address, uint64_t *value)
{

    return 0;
}

/* Fetches one instruction from memory, at the address specified by
     the program counter. Does not modify the machine's state. The
     resulting instruction is stored in *instr. Returns 1 if the
     instruction is a valid non-halt instruction, or 0 (zero)
     otherwise. */
int fetchInstruction(machine_state_t *state, y86_instruction_t *instr)
{

    return 0;
}
```

```
typedef enum y86_icode {
  I_HALT      = 0x0,
  I_NOP       = 0x1,
  I_RRMVXX    = 0x2,
  I_IRMOVQ    = 0x3,
  I_RMMOVQ    = 0x4,
  I_MRMOVQ    = 0x5,
  I_OPQ       = 0x6,
  I_JXX       = 0x7,
  I_CALL      = 0x8,
  I_RET       = 0x9,
  I_PUSHQ     = 0xA,
  I_POPQ      = 0xB,
  I_INVALID   = 0xE,
  I_TOO_SHORT = 0xF
} y86_icode_t;

typedef enum y86_reg {
  R_RAX = 0x0,
  R_RCX = 0x1,
  R_RDX = 0x2,
  R_RBX = 0x3,
  R_RSP = 0x4,
  R_RBP = 0x5,
  R_RSI = 0x6,
  R_RDI = 0x7,
  R_R8  = 0x8,
  R_R9  = 0x9,
  R_R10 = 0xA,
  R_R11 = 0xB,
  R_R12 = 0xC,
  R_R13 = 0xD,
  R_R14 = 0xE,
  R_NONE = 0xF
} y86_register_t;

typedef enum y86_condition {
  C_NC = 0x0,
  C_LE = 0x1,
  C_L  = 0x2,
  C_E  = 0x3,
  C_NE = 0x4,
  C_GE = 0x5,
  C_G  = 0x6
} y86_condition_t;

typedef enum y86_operation {
  A_ADDQ = 0x0,
  A_SUBQ = 0x1,
  A_ANDQ = 0x2,
  A_XORQ = 0x3,
  A_MULQ = 0x4,
  A_DIVQ = 0x5,
  A_MODQ = 0x6
} y86_operation_t;

typedef struct instruction {

  y86_icode_t    icode;
  uint8_t        ifun;
  y86_register_t rA;
  y86_register_t rB;
  uint64_t       valC;
  
  uint64_t       location;
  uint64_t       valP;
} y86_instruction_t;

#define CC_ZERO_MASK     0x1
#define CC_SIGN_MASK     0x2
#define CC_CARRY_MASK    0x4
#define CC_OVERFLOW_MASK 0x8

typedef struct machine_state {
  
  uint8_t *programMap;
  uint64_t programSize;
  
  uint64_t programCounter;

  uint64_t registerFile[16];

  uint8_t conditionCodes;
  
} machine_state_t;
```

Comment: You have to read a byte of memory (which specifies the instruction) and then depending on the instruction read the additional data associated with that instruction, and fill in the `instr` argument. For example if the first byte is 0x00 (halt) then there's no further data to read, but if it's 0x20 (rrmovl) you need to read another byte and extract rA and rB from it.

Comment: @PaulHankin Hi, correct me if I'm wrong. I should use memReadByte to read first byte to determine the op code and function code if present, read addtional data when needed. What about memReadQuadLE? Do I only ever use it for when jumps are used? Also, I'm having trouble understanding the technical stuff. I'm not sure how I should use state and *value and literally read the byte from memory. I will update my question with uh, my failed attempt I suppose.

Comment: Wait I should use machine_state->, let me fix my attempt.

Comment: Your implementation of `memReadByte` looks correct to me. `memReadQuadLE` would me rather similar to `memReadByte`, but reading a 64 bit value rather than an 8 bit value. You need `memReadQuadLE` to read a 64 bit number which is presumably needed for jumps and other stuff whenever you need to read a 64 bit value from memory. I don't know the `y86` enough for giving more hints.